# Search and filter in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, templates, search, filter

I am trying to do search and filter on my homepage_content view but i get search result in search input and below it filter(don't know how to filter need help) view please check my code.

**My Controller:**

**Templates.php**

```
function _filter_action()

{
    $this->load->module('store_items');
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
    if(isset($submit)) {
       if($this->input->post('search') == '')
            {
                redirect(base_url());
            }
       $str = $this->db->escape_str($search);
       $query = "SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE item_title LIKE '%$str%'" ;
       $mysql_query = $this->store_items->_custom_query($query);
        foreach ($mysql_query->result() as $row) {
           echo "<a href='index.php/mobile/phone/$row->item_url'><img src='small_pics/$row->small_pic' class='img-responsive' title='$row->item_title'>(\"".$row->item_title."\");'>" . $row->item_title . "<br><br>'</a>";

        }


    }

}

function _filter()

{
    $this->load->view('filter');
}


function _search_action()

{
   $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
    if(isset($submit)) {
      $this->load->view('search_result');
    }

}


function _search_bar()

{
    $this->load->view('search_bar');
}
```

**Store_items.php**

```
function _custom_query($mysql_query) 

{
    $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
    $query = $this->mdl_store_items->_custom_query($mysql_query);
    return $query;
}
```

**My View:**

**Search_bar.php**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= base_url() ?>" style="font-weight: bold; color:black">ShopBuzz</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <th>
          <form method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left col-md-11" action="<?= Modules::run('templates/_search_action')?>">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
          </th>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <br><br>
```

**Search_result.php**

```
<?php
    $this->load->module('store_items');
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
    $base_url = base_url('index.php');
    $this->load->module('site_settings');
    $currency_symbol = $this->site_settings->_get_currency_symbol();
    $str = $this->db->escape_str($search);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE item_title LIKE '%$str%'";
       if($this->input->post('search') == '')
            {
                redirect(base_url());
            }
       $mysql_query = $this->store_items->_custom_query($query);
        foreach ($mysql_query->result() as $row) {?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="background-color:white; min-height: 300px;">
    <div>
    <br>
    </div>
     <a href='<?=$base_url?>/mobile/phone/<?=$row->item_url?>'><img src='small_pics/<?=$row->small_pic?>' class='img-responsive' title='<?=$row->item_title?>'><?=$row->item_title?></a><br><?= nl2br('---------------------------------------------------') ?>
    </div>
    <?= nbs(120);?> 
    <div class="col-md-7" style="background-color:orange; min-height: 300px;">
    <div>
    <br>
    </div>
    <?php  
    if ($row->was_price == 0) {
      $discount = '';
      $discountper = '';
    }
    else{
        $discount = $row->was_price - $row->item_price;
        $discountper = intval($discount/$row->was_price*100)."% off";
    }
    ?>
     <?= "<h2>Price: ".$currency_symbol.number_format($row->item_price)."</h2><h3>".$discountper."</h3><h3>Highlights:</h3><br>Ram: ".$row->item_ram. "<br>Rom: " .$row->item_rom. "<br>Camera: " .$row->item_camera. "<br>Display: " .$row->item_display. "<br>Battery: " .$row->item_battery. "<br>Processor: " .$row->item_processor?><br><br><br><?= nl2br('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------') ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
}


?>
```

**filter.php**

```
<?php 
$this->load->module('store_items');

$search = $this->input->post('search');

$str = $this->db->escape_str($search);

$fetch_item_ram = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_ram) AS ram FROM store_items WHERE item_title LIKE '%$str%' GROUP BY item_ram"; 

$mysql_query_ram = $this->store_items->_custom_query($fetch_item_ram);

$fetch_item_rom = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_rom) AS rom FROM store_items WHERE item_title LIKE '%$str%' GROUP BY item_rom";

$mysql_query_rom = $this->store_items->_custom_query($fetch_item_rom);

$fetch_item_price = "SELECT '20000 - 30000' AS price, COUNT(*) FROM store_items
WHERE item_price >= 20000 AND item_price <= 30000
UNION
SELECT '30000 - 40000', COUNT(*) FROM store_items
WHERE item_price >= 30000 AND item_price <= 40000";

$mysql_query_price = $this->store_items->_custom_query($fetch_item_price);

$fetch_item_display = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_display) AS display FROM store_items WHERE item_title LIKE '%$str%' GROUP BY item_display";

$mysql_query_display = $this->store_items->_custom_query($fetch_item_display);

?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-0">
      <div class="well">
      <h3 align="center">Search Filter</h3>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type1" class="control-label">Price</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="type1">
              <option value="priceselected" selected="" disabled="">Please Select Price</option>
              <?php foreach ($mysql_query_price->result() as $row) {?>
              <option value="price"><?php echo $row->price; ?></option><?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type1" class="control-label">Ram</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="type1">
            <option value="ramselected" selected="" disabled="">Please Select Ram</option>
              <?php foreach ($mysql_query_ram->result() as $row) {?>
              <option value="ram"><?php echo $row->ram; ?></option><?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type1" class="control-label">Rom</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="type1">
            <option value="romselected" selected="" disabled="">Please Select Rom</option>
              <?php foreach ($mysql_query_rom->result() as $row) {?>
              <option value="rom"><?php echo $row->rom; ?></option><?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type1" class="control-label">Screen Size</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="type1">
            <option value="displayselected" selected="" disabled="">Please Select Display</option>
              <?php foreach ($mysql_query_display->result() as $row) {?>
              <option value="display"><?php echo $row->display; ?></option><?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-search" role="button"></a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Homepage_content.php**

```
<br>
<br>
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <?php 
        echo Modules::run('templates/_search_bar');
        ?>

        <?php 
        $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
        if (isset($submit)) {
          if($this->input->post('search') == '')
            {
                echo "<br><strong>No Data Found</strong>";
            }
          echo Modules::run('templates/_filter');
        }
        ?>

        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
<?php
echo Modules::run('homepage_blocks/_draw_blocks');
?>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <a href="#">CLICK HERE</a><p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <a href="#">CLICK HERE</a><p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
```

[Please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ5hv.jpg)

Comment: Tip I am not to sure why you have all that query on the view you should create a model function intead http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#what-is-a-model

Comment: i just testing it.. the search result is showing on it's input please help